# Optimal way to find consecutive values above threshold in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

What would be the fastest way to find a minimum amount of consecutive values above a threshold ?

i.e.

Suppose I have a vector of values:

```
std::vector<int> v = [10 25 8 49 50 61 55 45 34 10 8]
```

A simple approach would be to iterate over the vector;

```
int threshold = 40;
int consecutive = 5;

bool success = false;

for(int i = 0; i < v.size()-consecutive; ++i)
{
    int counter = 0;

    while(i+counter < v.size())
    {
        if(v[i+counter] > threshold)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    if(counter >= consecutive)
    {
        success = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: for @cmbasnett

Expected result is to have `success = true` if `5` consecutive values over `40` are found in the vector `v`, `false` otherwise.

Comment: Sounds like codility. You might want to let us know hat the expected result of your example is.

Comment: Edited with expected result, codility ?

Comment: what should be the answer if more than `5` consecutive values over `40` are found in the **v**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `std::search_n()`:

```
bool success = search_n(begin(v), end(v), 5, 40, [](int x, int y) { return y < x; }) != end(v);
```

[Live version](http://ideone.com/H4HUqJ).

You could write your own optimized version a bit more efficiently by skipping forward past a failing element, a bit like a Boyer-Moore-Hoorspool search:

```
template<typename It, typename T>
bool contains_n_gt_x(It first, It last, size_t n, const T& x) {
    for (auto curr = first; first != last;) {
        first = find_if(curr, last, [&](const auto& y){ return x < y; });
        curr = find_if(first, last, [&](const auto& y){ return !(x < y); });
        if (distance(first, curr) >= n) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Live version](http://ideone.com/Kf2YWv).

Comment: Just curious: do you think this would be just as fast as the loop in the question?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah the `search_n` version should be pretty much as fast as the loop in the question. The second version should be faster.